# Mac OS. Is there a way to open compare directly, skip the `Launch 'bc3' [Y/n]?`

Tags: git, beyondcompare4

I am using the Beyond compare and set it as the git merge tool. 
Now I face a problem, every time I type the command line `git difftool`.
The code below show:

> Viewing (1/3): 'followUpTeam.html'
>   Launch 'bc3' [Y/n]?

I am using an iMac and Beyond compare 4.

Is there a way to open compare directly, skip the `Launch 'bc3' [Y/n]?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instruct `git difftool` not to prompt you for a single invocation by passing it the [`-y` / `--no-prompt`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool#git-difftool--y) argument:

```
git difftool -y
```

If you never wish to be prompted you can use the [`difftool.prompt`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool#git-difftool-difftoolprompt) setting:

```
git config [--global] difftool.prompt false
```

As always with `git config`, the [`--global`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config---global) setting may be used to set your default value for all repositories (in `~/.gitconfig`) or omit it to set the value for a particular repository (in that repository's `.git/config` file).